# Fill DataTables buttons with data from columns

Tags: jquery, laravel, datatables

I use DataTables to create my table, but I have two buttons in my last column whose data attributes should be filled with data from the other columns of that row. Is this even possible?

I had this already when I was trying with another method. My goal is now to get where is now $(value....) to be set correctly:

```
$('#table_id').DataTable({
                ajax: {
                    url: '/admin/users3/qryUsers',
                    dataSrc: ''
                },
                columns: [
                    {data: 'id'},
                    {data: 'name'},
                    {data: 'email'},
                    {data: 'active'},
                    {data: 'admin'},
                    {
                        data: null,
                        defaultContent: '<form action="/admin/users3/${value.id}" method="post" class="deleteForm">\n' +
                            '@method('delete')\n' +
                            '            @csrf\n' +
                            '            <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm">\n' +
                            '                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success btn-edit"\n' +
                            '                        data-toggle="tooltip"\n' +
                            '                        data-user="${value.name}"\n' +
                            '            data-id="${value.id}"\n' +
                            '            data-email="${value.email}"\n' +
                            '            data-active="${value.active}"\n' +
                            '            data-admin="${value.admin}"\n' +
                            '            title="Edit ${value.name}">\n' +
                            '        <i class="fas fa-edit"></i>\n' +
                            '    </button>\n' +
                            '    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-delete"\n' +
                            '            data-toggle="tooltip"\n' +
                            '            data-user="${value.name}"\n' +
                            '            data-id="${value.id}"\n' +
                            '            title="Delete ${value.name}">\n' +
                            '        <i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i>\n' +
                            '    </button>\n' +
                            '</div>\n' +
                            '</form>'
                    }
                ]
            });
```

I don't know if it's possible to do when initializing the datatable, or if it has to be done with jquery afterwards, if so, help on that is also welcome!

Comment: Can you use alternative solution like  https://bootstrap-table.com/
I can help you with BootstrapTable

Comment: No sorry the task was to use datatable

Comment: Use [`render`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render) instead of `defaultcontent` (look for the *render( data, type, row, meta)* example in the linked page)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `columnDefs` to render custom elements to DataTable

```
$('#table').DataTable( {
    ajax: {
                url: '/admin/users3/qryUsers',
                dataSrc: ''
            },
            columns: [
                {data: 'id'},
                {data: 'name'},
                {data: 'email'},
                {data: 'active'},
                {data: 'admin'},
        ],
        columnDefs: [
            {
                // The `data` parameter refers to the data for the cell (defined by the
                // `data` option, which defaults to the column being worked with, in
                // this case `data: 0`.
                "render": function ( data, type, row ) {
                    return [
                        '<button class="btn btn-outline-success btn-edit">Edit</button>',
                        '<button class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-delete">Delete</button>'
                    ].join('');

                },
                "targets": 3
            }
        ]
    });
    $('#table').on('click', '.btn-edit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();    
        var table = $('#table').DataTable();
        var data = table.row($(this).closest('tr')).data();
        console.log(data);
        // Submit data to server via AJAX
    });
```